# Why can't I create an array with size determined by a global variable?

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables

Why does the array `a` not get initialized by global variable `size`?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int size = 5;

int main()
{
    int a[size] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf("%d", a[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation error is shown as

> variable-sized object may not be initialized

According to me, the array should get initialized by `size`.

And what would be the answer if I insist on using global variable (if it is possible)?

Comment: Use `-std=c99` when compiling with GCC to enable variable size arrays.

Comment: They're already enabled - if he was in c89 mode, the error would be something like `ISO C90 forbids variable length array 'a'`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In C99, 6.7.8/3:

> The type of the entity to be
>   initialized shall be an array of
>   unknown size or an object type that is
>   not a variable length array type.

6.6/2:

> A constant expression can be evaluated
>   during translation rather than runtime

6.6/6:

> An integer constant expression
>   shall have integer type and shall only
>   have operands that are integer
>   constants, enumeration constants,
>   character constants, sizeof
>   expressions whose results are integer
>   constants, and floating constants that
>   are the immediate operands of casts.

6.7.5.2/4:

> If the size is an integer constant
>   expression and the element type has a
>   known constant size, the array type is
>   not a variable length array type;
>   otherwise, the array type is a
>   variable length array type.

`a` has variable length array type, because `size` is not an integer constant expression. Thus, it cannot have an initializer list.

In C90, there are no VLAs, so the code is illegal for that reason.

In C++ there are also no VLAs, but you could make `size` a `const int`. That's because in C++ you can use `const int` variables in ICEs. In C you can't.

Presumably you didn't intend `a` to have variable length, so what you need is:

```
#define size 5
```

If you actually did intend `a` to have variable length, I suppose you could do something like this:

```
int a[size];
int initlen = size;
if (initlen > 5) initlen = 5;
memcpy(a, (int[]){1,2,3,4,5}, initlen*sizeof(int));
```

Or maybe:

```
int a[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size && i < 5; ++i) {
    a[i] = i+1;
}
```

It's difficult to say, though, what "should" happen here in the case where size != 5. It doesn't really make sense to specify a fixed-size initial value for a variable-length array.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to tell the compiler what size the array is if you're giving an initializer.  The compiler will figure out the size based on how many elements you're initializing it with.

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Then you can even let the compiler tell you the size by getting the total size of the array in bytes `sizeof(a)` and dividing it by the size of one element `sizeof(a[0])`:

```
int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

Comment: What if I also wanted to initialize everything to zero, for example?  

   `int myArray [numRows][numCols] = {{0}};`

Is there a way to skip the numRows and numCols variables on the LHS, but not have to write out all the zeroes on the RHS?

Comment: Wouldn't it be less ambiguous to refer to the number of actual elements in the array as *length* and the number of bytes comprising the array at the memory level as *size* ? This would have the benefit of being more compliant with the standard meaning used by the `sizeof` operator, which simply computes and returns the number of raw bytes of the array.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler cannot assume that the value of size is still 5 by the time main() gets control. If you want a true constant in an old-style C project, use:

```
#define size 5
```

Comment: Good point. Solution can be also use of new fashioned `const int size = 5`

Answer (score 6):

`size` is a variable, and C does not allow you to declare (**edit:** C99 allows you to declare them, just not initialize them like you are doing) arrays with variable size like that. If you want to create an array whose size is a variable, use [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) or make the size a constant.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that your compiler is not C99 Compliant...speaking of which, which compiler are you using? If it's gcc you need to pass the switch '-std=c99'.... if you are using a pre-C99 compiler, that statement is illegal, if that's the case, do this:

```
int main() { 
   int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5}; 
   printf("%d",a[0]); 
   return 0; 
}
```

In pre-C99 standard compilers, use a constant instead of a variable.

**Edit:** You can find out more about the C99 standard [here](http://www.deitel.com/Default.aspx?tabid=204)... and [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)....

Comment: In C99 you can declare a variable sized array, but you cannot then initialize it in this manner. The problem is exactly what the error message says.

Comment: In this case, the problem is not VLAs support or not,  it's providing an initializer to a vla - which is not allowed.

Comment: That's very interesting, I had no idea you could do that. The post is a little misleading though, as it doesn't mention the problem is the initialization and not the declaration. Anyway, +1 for teaching me something new.

Comment: The compiler is conforming (6.7.8/3).

Answer (score 4):

The compiler needs to know the size of the array while declaring it.
Because the size of an array doesn't change after its declaration.
If you put the size of the array in a variable, you can imagine that the value of that variable will change when the program is executed.
In this case, the compiler will be forced to allocate extra memory to this array.
In this case, this is not possible because the array is a static data structure allocated on the stack.
I hope that this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create arrays with globally variable size the same reason why you cannot create an array with size determined by a variable in general. The reason is because C++ enables manual memory management, which let's be honest is the reason why we learn this language, and when we allocate memory, we need to keep in mind the advantages and drawbacks of its two types and what we can do with it.

Stack memory literally implements the stack data structure. It has fixed size (a few megabytes as far as I know), and when you put any data on the stack, you push it to the top. Stack fits perfectly for **scoped variables** that are supposed to only live for a restricted amount of time, which means it will disappear as soon as they see }. Stacks use *functions* as a unit of grouping all variables, and whenever we call any function (including main), it pushes the total amount of memory this function uses, which is the sum of all variables it allocates. This total size is called *stack frame*, and it must be constant. Otherwise, if we allocate an array dynamically on the stack:

```cpp
int size;
scanf("%d", %size);
int array[size];
```

We don't know how much space we need to reserve for the array and its stack frame responsively, which makes this a forbidden operations. *You can*, however, initialise it with a constant and constant expression:

```cpp
constexprt int getSize(int n){
    return n * 2; //This can be anything, I just multiplied to get arbitrary value.
}

const int size = 45;
int constantArray[size]; //Works
int constantExpressionArray[getSize(2)]; //Also works
```

The reason why constant works is because they are always assured to have the same and known size, and furthermore they don't take up space in memory but compilers just substitute all constant calls with their respective values. Constant expresions also are functions that are executed in the compile-time, which means all values must be known, and then it just substitudes the result (that must always be the same) into its call, which assure the compiler in both cases the size of the arrays are going to be the same (45 for the first one and 4 for the second one).

If you want to have an array with size that veries each time you execute it, you should either allocate it dynamically:

```cpp
int* dynamicArray = new int[variableSize];
```

or use `std::vector`:

```cpp
std::vector<int> dynamicArray(variableSize);
```

In the latter case it sets `variableSize` to be the *capacity*,which is the length of the array it needs to exceed to resize. If you use it responsibly, you will end up simply using the array underneath it and will only suffer from the performance penalties imposed by dynamically allocating memory and jumping between the functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h> 

/* int size=5; */
#define size 5 /* use this instead*/
/*OR*/
int a[size]={1,2,3,4,5};  /* this*/

int main() 
{ 
    int a[size]={1,2,3,4,5}; 
    printf("%d",a[0]); 
    return 0; 
}
```

`int size` means that `size` is a **variable** and C does not allow **variable**`size` arrays.

I am using VS2008 where using

```
const int size=5;
```

allows

```
int a[size]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: why can't i use global variables?

Comment: @ashish: because global variables are still variables (the clue's in the name). Suppose somebody assigned the value `1` to `size` somewhere before your code to define `a`. Then you'd be trying to initialize an array of size 1 with an initializer list of size 5. Rather than trying to sort this mess out, the standard forbids it.

Comment: "size is a variable and C does not allow variable size arrays." we should add a point to your comment that: if we initialize the variable, C does allow defining an array using that variable. E.g. int size = 5; int a[size]; is totally fine.