# Array size in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, arrays, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-const declaration of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377411/non-const-declaration-of-array)

My compiler gcc allows

```
int n = 5;
int a[n];
```

Other compiler visual c gives error. It says array of size 0 cannot be created.
Which compiler is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct... these are compilers... In fact, std C assumes the size of a static array needs to be fixed and set by a constant value. use Define instead, or use malloc for dynamic arrays

Comment: see the other question - std C allows dynamic arrays (surely you are using C99 - 10 years old :))