# Initializing an array with an expression

Tags: c++, c, arduino

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I create an array with size determined by a global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427336/why-cant-i-create-an-array-with-size-determined-by-a-global-variable)

I am trying to initialise an array using an expression as seen below, then assigning all values to zero.

```
byte arg_listB[2*num_args+10]={0};
```

This produces the error:

```
error: variable-sized object 'arg_listB' may not be initialized
```

but if I replace the expression with an actual number it works

```
byte arg_listB[10]={0};
```

WHY? And how do I fix this?

Comment: In C++, you fix this by taking advantage of things like `std::array` and, more relevantly, `std::vector`. In C (C99 at least), you can use VLAs as part of the language.

Comment: @chris I don't think `std::array` would solve it... but `std::vector` sure would!

Comment: @oldrinb, I almost always include `std::array` in my suggestions of `std::vector`. The former is a good replacement for fixed-size arrays.

Comment: @chris but `std::array` doesn't fix this particular problem, since it requires a compile-time constant for the size. What they could use is `constexpr`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I know, but they really are a pair except for the fact that you hear "use vectors" so often that you never end up using `std::array` at all (partially because it's next gen as well). In this case, my point was to use the standard containers instead of raw arrays/pointers, and even if `std::array` doesn't come in handy right now, it will later.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a static array, you must use a constant value, such as a literal or a constant variable.  You can use the `#define` keyword to assign a name to a literal, or declare and initialize a constant variable, if you simply want to make your code more readable and easier to manage:

```
#define NUM_ARGS 5
/*...*/
byte arg_listB[NUM_ARGS];
```

However, in order to use an expression to set the size of an array, you will have to create a dynamic array using pointers.  How this is done depends on which language you are using.  In C, you could use the `calloc` function to create your array like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h> //required for calloc
/*...*/
int num_args = 5;
byte* arg_listB = (byte*)calloc(2*num_args+10, sizeof(byte));
```

This will dynamically create a block of memory the size of your array and assign the address of the first byte to your pointer.  One thing to note is that `calloc` automatically initializes the elements in your array to 0, so that part is already done for you.  Of course, you will also want to remember to clean up the memory you allocated once you are done with your array like this:

```
free(arg_listB);
```

Technically, you could use these functions in C++ if you include the `<cstdlib>` header.  However, C++ has its own special keywords for dynamic memory allocation:  `new` and `delete`.  These can be used like so:

```
/*...*/
int num_args = 5;
byte* arg_listB = new byte[2*num_args+10];
//initialize your array

//free the memory when done with the array
delete[] arg_listB;
```

As noted in comments, you will need to initialize your array after you declare it, and do not forget to free the memory after you are done with it.  As there is much more to memory management and dynamic arrays than can be covered here, I would highly recommend looking into them.  Here are a few articles that might help:

C:
[Arrays](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/c-arrays.html),
[Dynamic Memory](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c.html)

C++: [Dynamic Memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

Answer (score 0):

The initializer for an array declaration only works for statically-sized arrays, not dynamically-sized arrays.  You can do one of two things - either make `num_args` a compile-time constant (with a `#define`, probably), or allocate and initialize separately:

```
byte arg_listB[2*num_args+10];
bzero(arg_listB, 2*num_args+10);
```

Comment: Please don't keep preferring the #define in C++.

Comment: ... and don't suggest `bzero`, it's deprecated POSIX ([`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) maybe?) though tbh I'd rather use `std::fill(std::begin(arg_listB), std::end(arg_listB), 0);` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your C++ tag is erroneous, that language doesn't have the concept of variable length array (VLA) that you are using, that is declaring an array where the size depends on a variable. (C++ has other tools for this goal.)

In C, VLA cannot be initialized, you'd have to assign to the individual members or set the bytes via the C library function `memset`.