# can't use a const global variable as array no. of elements in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I declared a constant global variable 'MEM_PRIMES' and I wanna use it in the struct below as the array elements' number but it errors saying "variably modified 'primes' at file scope.

```
/* global data */

const unsigned int MEM_PRIMES = 100;

struct{
   char *filename;
   FILE *pfile;
   int nrec;
   unsigned long long primes[MEM_PRIMES];
   size_t index;
}global = {"D:\\C\\C files\\mytext4.bin", NULL, 0, {2ULL, 3ULL, 5ULL}, 3};
```

Comment: Why not `#define MEM_PRIMES  100`?

Comment: Use `#define MEM_PRIMES 100;`.

Read this [answer][1] too.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427336/why-cant-i-create-an-array-with-size-determined-by-a-global-variable

Comment: @G.Samaras Hmm.. An `=` ?

Comment: Missed that @DavidC.Rankin.

Comment: @GSamaras you have an extra semicolon there

Answer (score 2):

`const` doesn't really ensure that the storage cannot be modified; you can take the address, cast away the `const` and modify it, so I believe that is why you get the complaint.

```
#define MEM_PRIMES 100
```

will fix it and is the C way.

Comment: The explanation is likely to be true on modern desktop systems, but it's not really an explanation for why you can't do this with `const` in C. While it may sometimes be true that "you can take the address, cast away the const and modify it", it is undefined behavior to do so, so this is no reason for not allowing you to use `const` variables in this manner.

Comment: The reasons are best described as "historical" :)

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do this in C, like you can in C++. You'll have to:

```
#define MEM_PRIMES 100
```

or similar.

The actual error message you're getting arises from the fact that you *are* allowed to have variable length arrays in C99 and later - you're just not allowed to have them at file scope (or in `struct`s at all, for that matter) because the size would need to be determined at compile time. So rather than chewing you out for using a `const int` instead of an actual constant, your compiler is actually thinking you want a VLA, and telling you that you can't have one here.

Comment: VLAs can't be members of structures either

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yep, that too.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a `const int` variable is deemed to be a variable in C and cannot be used in contexts where a compile time constant is required, such dimensions of a global array or an array embedded in a structure (nor in a `case` clause within a `switch`, nor …).

While `#define MEM_PRIMES 100` (suggested by the other answers) will work, I'd use:

```
enum { MEM_PRIMES = 100 };
```

The reasons are detailed in [`static const` vs `#define`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c/1674459#1674459).