# Why won't scanf save my requested "size of an array 'n' " and pass it onto the for loop?

Tags: c, scanf

'scanf' won't pass on my the value n into the for loop

appreciate your time to help thanks.  terminal prints the size of array.  I hope to scan for that value and call it 'n' .  This value 'n' is then suppose to be passed down to the loop where random numbers less then 999 are assigned to different parts of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
int arraySize;
int randN;
int rand();
int parameter = 999;

int main()
{
printf("What is the size of the array\n");
scanf("%d\n", &n);
//here is the scanf  


int i;
for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
{
    int array[n];

    randN=rand();
    if (randN  <= parameter)
 {
        array[i]=randN;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: scanf is C. In C++ you can use cin.

Comment: What value does n have immediately after the scanf statement? "scanf() returns the number of items assigned into variables. Since assignment into variables stops when given invalid input for a certain format specifier, this can tell you if you've input all your data correctly."

Comment: i hope n to have the value that is entered into the terminal after the printf @MikeJRamsey56

Comment: Firstly, you are creating and destroying your array at each iteration. (Why?) Secondly, you are terminating your program immediately after the first iteration. (Why?) If that's your intent, then your program look fine to me. It does what you asked it to do.

Comment: The value that you input has to be an integer > 0.  To AnT's point, move int array[n] to a line before the for loop. Also, make randN be a value between 0 and 999. randN = rand() % 999;

Answer (score 1):

The array is declared as the first line in the body of the loop.

This means, for every loop iteration, the array is created, one element is set, and then the array ceases to exist.

If you want the loop to populate the whole array, declare the array BEFORE the loop.   That will also ensure the array can be used AFTER the loop .... with all its elements as populated in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the \n at the end of format string. scanf tries to get input as specified in the format string, the \n forces the user to enter additional newline

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Comment: This is close to the answer.  "forces the user to enter additional newline" --> "forces the user to enter additional non-white-space".

Answer (score 0):

See answer of user3279954

See comment of AnT

the "return 0;" statements will terminate your program in the first iteration of the loop, regardless of the value returned in the call to rand()

Also: Don't declare library functions (like rand()) yourself, instead, include the appropriate header file, here stdlib.h which was included already.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
int arraySize;
int randN;
int parameter = 999;

int main()
{
    printf("What is the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int array[n];
    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {
        // This loop below should be optimized for any productive use
        // easy solutions like random%1000 (yielding values from 0
        // to 999) will bias some values over others.
        do {
            randN=rand();
        } while (randN > parameter);
        // This loop above should be optimized for any productive use

        array[i]=randN;
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf("%i ", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you suggest i return n?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, what result you expect from your code. But you can check what my code does and take what you need to get yours to do what you want it to do.

Comment: and you are stating they are not optimized?

Comment: why the do statement? ultimately I need an array of size n to have values between 0 and 999 then I have another task to do after that

Comment: with rand yielding values from 0 .. (2^31-1), the test randN <= 999 will almost always yield false.

Comment: if you need an array of n random values in the range 0 .. 999 then this example code will provide that. If you don't care for some bias, you can replace the do loop by "randN = rand % (parameter + 1);" and get on with it. However, if you need a 0 to be as probably as a 999, then you will have to do more sophisticated optimization that just % 1000.

Comment: yeah I figured the way I was getting my 'n's was very inefficient but was the first thing that came to mind

Comment: is rand with math.h?

Comment: actually, it's declared in stdlib.h. In C, you have to differentiate between declaration (i.e. "int foo();") and implementation (i.e. "int foo() { return 42; }"). The declaration normally belongs in foo.h, the implementation in foo.c. So, stdlib.h contains a line effectively boiling down to "int rand();" and the actual function is in a file provided by your compiler, in most cases something called like "libc.a", or "stdc.lib" or something similar.

Comment: could you clarify a tad bit more on "optimized" use? and with the do statement does it imply randN = rand() when randN is not greater then parameter?

Comment: intuitively I feel it should be  do {
            randN=rand();
        } while (randN < parameter);  --have randN = rand() only when randN is less then parameter

Comment: I just copied your `randN  <= parameter`, so, if is `randN` has to be smaller (and not equal - thus yielding values from 0 to 998), then yes, the check has to be `randN < parameter` (but then it should have been the same in your post ;)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so there are some things with your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
int arraySize;
int randN;
int rand();
int parameter = 999;

int main()
{
    printf("What is the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n); // remove the \n

    // in C, you have to use a const to create an array
    const int arrSize = n;
    // create the array BEFORE, entering the for loop
    int array[arrSize];
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {
       // this guarantees that you will get a number less than "parameter"
        randN=rand() % parameter;
        array[i]=randN; 
        // return 0; you don't want this return
    }

    // so you can see what got stored
    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
        printf("%d ", array[i]);

return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: added a printf for the values in the array**

Comment: "in C, you have to use a const to create an array" where did you learn that? Of course, it doesn't have to be const, but the array size wont change when you modify the variable.

Comment: @BodoThiesen just from every C compiler I have used, i get something like "Error: Non-static-const variable in array dimension"... maybe I don't know how to configure it?

Comment: variable array sizes only work as local variables. You probably got that error from an attempt to define a file scope array. Just do the test right now ;)

Comment: @BodoThiesen if I change "arrSize" for "n" in my example, I get that error, maybe something is wrong with my compilers? :(

Comment: what is rand() % parameter, specifically '%'

Comment: @user7117719 its the modulus operator, when you make a division by hand, do you remember that number that was left at the bottom of the operation? thats what modulus gives you, so, lets say that you want numbers less than 10, if your rand() gives you a 450, when you get the modulus  ( 450 % 10 ) you will get a 0, because it is an exact division, but if rand() gives you 36 (36 % 10) you will get a 6... rand() 168, you will get an 8, did I explained my self?

Comment: karkazz what compiler? @user7117719: What karkazz was trying to explain: / returns the integer division quotient, and % return the reminder. So, for "for (i = 0; ; ++i) { print("%i ", i % 3); }" the program will print 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 and so on. i / 3 would have printed 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 and so on.

Comment: @BodoThiesen Right now, compilers for ios, i'm not close to a computer... but usually gcc from xcode in mac os, gcc in redhat

Comment: I compiled my code containing that offending lines `int n;[...] int array[n];` with `gcc (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.3, pie-0.6.3) 4.9.3` using command line options `-W -Wall -Wextra` - I didn't even get a warning on that.

Comment: @BodoThiesen Thanks!!, I will look into that as soon as I get to my computer, I am so curious why I get that message... Greetings!

Comment: @karkazz yes i remember studying mod in discrete math.  just had to clarify the syntax.

Comment: @karkazz looking at my requirements i was told to use modulus. seems like a way quicker and easy way for keeping the values below a 1000.  is this what you mean by optimization @BodoThiesen?

Comment: yea. It causes some bias, but especially when learning to code, it doesn't matter - only important, to keep that in mind. Read the man page on `rand`, there are some statements about this as well.

Comment: @BodoThiesen, so I just searched for this and found there are several questions in SO about this, depending on the compiler and the options you use to compile, variable length arrays may or may not cause the error I told you... so I updated my compiler and the error went away, seems like some time has passed since the last time I actually made an C program :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427336/why-cant-i-create-an-array-with-size-determined-by-a-global-variable
https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Declaring-Arrays