# Getting Error While Calculating Average in Array More Than 4 Elements in C

Tags: arrays, c, average

I did the below program in C. It works fine up to number 4, if you type number 5 forward I'm getting Segmentation fault: 11 error? Why? I cannot find where is the error. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{ 
  srand(time(NULL));
  
  int sum, i, input;
  int array [input];
  float average;
  sum = average = 0;
  int size = sizeof (array) / sizeof(array[0]);

  printf("Type the value of your array : ");
  scanf("%d", &input);

  printf("The size of your array is : %.2d \n", input);

  for (i = 0; i < input; i++)
  {
    array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
  }

  // loop for printing results

  for (i = 0; i < input; i++)
  {
    printf("Element %d; %d \n", i, array[i]);
  }
 
  for(i = 0; i < input; i ++){
    sum = sum + array[i];
  }

  average = (float)sum / i;
  printf("The average of array values is %.2f \n", average);
  
  
  return 0;
  };
```

Comment: Are you compiling using the C99 specification?

Comment: What do you mean C99 specification?

Comment: How are you compiling your program?  If you're using a command line, can you show your compilation command?

Comment: `int input; int array[input];` is OH SO VERY WRONG!

Comment: Yes, I'm using terminal gcc AverageWwight.c

Comment: Try using `gcc -std=c99 AverageWwight.c`.

Comment: @pmg, I agree.  However, in C99, it actually is valid.  See the [first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427336/why-cant-i-create-an-array-with-size-determined-by-a-global-variable).

Comment: No luck, still giving me the same after number 4, Segmentation fault: 11. It worked fine up to number 4

Comment: @DanielWalker pmg is correct. In c99 you can have variable arrays as shown by your link. However, in this case ‘input’ hasn’t been initialized to anything. This is very bad...

Comment: Huh.  Good to know.  I've never used variable-length arrays because the very thought of them makes my skin crawl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The defects in the code:**

1. Used the variable `input` uninitialized to initialize an array.
2. Attempted to get the size of the array which has incorrectly determined previously.
3. The variable `size` is never used in the entire program (redundant declaration).

**Note:** I'll be using `-std=c99` (C99 standard)

```
gcc -std=c99 -o main main.c; ./main
```

---

**Code redefined (read the added comment to get the issue solved):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int sum, i, input;
    float average;
    sum = average = 0;

    printf("Type the value of your array : ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    int array[input]; // placing after defining of 'input'
    // int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); // unused variable

    printf("The size of your array is : %.2d \n", input);

    for (i = 0; i < input; i++)
        array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;

    // loop for printing results

    for (i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        printf("Element %d; %d \n", i, array[i]);
        sum += array[i];
    }

    average = (float) sum / i;

    printf("The average of array values is %.2f \n", average);

    return 0;
};
```

---

**This will output:**

```
Type the value of your array : 10 
The size of your array is : 10 
Element 0; 6
Element 1; 14
Element 2; 66
Element 3; 73
Element 4; 19
Element 5; 14
Element 6; 62
Element 7; 78
Element 8; 31
Element 9; 31
The average of array values is 39.40
```

Comment: Ohhh I got it. Awesome! Thank you so much @Rohan Bari